# Routing in Kohana 3.3.1

Tags: php, url-routing, kohana

I recently started working with the kohana 3.3.1 framework and ran into some problems.

I want to create different routes for different entry points. Right now, this is the default route, which seems to work fine(I think):

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

When I go to the website, it displays 'hello, world!'.

I have a controller called Street, located in application/classes/Controller/Street.php.

The code to this controller is:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Street extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body('hello, street!');
    }
```

The problem is, that I want to type /something behind the URI, and it should redirect to the defined controller, and action. But it doesn't seem to work. I get 404 error's when I type ANYTHING behind the default URI.

For routes, i use this

```
/**
 * Set the routes. Each route must have a minimum of a name, a URI and a set of
 * defaults for the URI.
 */


Route::set('test1', 'street/<id>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'street',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I just tried @Darsstar 's instruction to go to /index.php/street, and it worked! 
But now, when I try to go to /index.php/street/derp, I get an error saying

> The requested URL derp was not found on this server.

So it's not yet working properly I guess

Comment: Is your controller correct (check case sensitivity in the name, correct folder, has the right methods)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kingkero.  
`code`Route::set('test1', 'test/<id>')
 ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'test',
  'action'     => 'index',
 ));`/code`

If I have a test controller in the map controller(just like welcome) and action_index(just like in the welcome controller) it should work right? But when I browse to ../test, it tells me requested resource not found!

Comment: You're welcome but did it solve the problem? If not, please provide more code (like the controller you want to access)

Comment: I updated my first post with some more details

Comment: And if you go to `index.php/test` does that work? Because then it is most likely to do with your .htaccess. Oh and 'test/<id>' won't match the URI 'test' because the id parameter is not between parenthesis and therefor required. The default route will match it however and should give dispatch you to  Controller_Test::action_index().

Comment: Hi @Darsstar. Thanks for your reply!  Scratch the test controller, I provided some information in my original post. What route do you recommend to get the the action_index() function of the Street controller? And wich URI should I enter to get routed there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `/index.php/street` version works go and read the [Clean URLs tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls) if you haven't already. If you have, double check everything!

If you have just those two routes, in that order, `/index.php/street/derp` should have matched the route 'test1'.

The error message 'The requested URL derp was not found on this server.' says you went to `/index.php/derp`, not `index.php/street/derp`. Which would match the default route and be dispatched to Controller_Derp::action_index(), but it doesn't exist so Request_Internal::execute() throws a HTTP_Exception_404.

The default route is more of and example. The is a [discussion on Kohana's issue tracker](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4642) to remove it since a catchall default route is a bad practice. Routes should be specific. I recommend to remove it.

And if you think having a catchall route is a good way to catch all 404 requests, please let the [Custom Error Pages tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages) prove you wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I will start reading this information. I don't want to have just two routes, but when i enter a nonexisting url, it should redirect the request to something I choose, for example some not valid page or something.

Comment: Not yet, haven't gotten around to trying it. But thanks for the help!